# How to modify Django Rest Framework incoming request?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am building a web app using Django that is pretty much only serving as the API server. I have a single-page application that connects to it as well as an Android client. I have a need to modify some of the incoming POST requests that are coming through.

My two use cases:

- If during the registration process the user does not select an avatar image to upload (which is a simple TextField that is the URL to the image), I should be able to insert the default avatar URL. So something like `if request.data["avatar"] is None: <use default>`
- The incoming "timestamp" requests from the Android client are all unix timestamps. I would like to convert this to Django's datetime on the fly - so, current request comes in with `date_time = 1473387225`, I'd like to convert that to a DateTime object.

Now, I'm already doing something similar for certain POST parameters. The way I do it right now is in the `post()` function of my generic `ListCreateApiView` I would directly modify the request object and then call the `self.create()` with that new request object. Is this the right way, or is there a much better way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django-rest-framework these things can be done by [serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).
For `avatar` use an [URLField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#urlfield) with default value.
For the timestamp you should probably create a [custom field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site: http://www.cdrf.co It is an easily navigable display of all the methods available on a given class. You can simply use this to overwrite the View you are using. If a model ViewSet, you likely want `perform_create` and `perform_update`.

I often do something like this:

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        data = self.request.data

        # make some changes to self.request here

        serializer.save(
                #change some things here
                field='some new value'
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a number of ways. As a part of your validation or in the `to_internal_value` of the request serializer or in a custom field serializer.

Heres an example of doing this as a part of a custom field serializer.

```
class AccountCreationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    avatar = AvatarField(
        required=False
        allow_files=True
    )

# Custom Field Serializer
class AvatarField(serializers.FilePathField):
    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        user_defined_path = super(AvatarField, self).to_internal_value(value)
        if user_defined_path:
            return user_defined_path

        return default_path
```